# windows installer missing drivers after bcd edit

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb, windows-installation

sorry if my English is not so good.

I have been making a bootable usb stick with both windows 10 and windows seven installation inside it. I prepared the stick and copied the windows installation files from ISOs to the stick. The windows 10 installation files are inside a folder named x86 on the stick like the original iso

I used visual bcd editor to modify the bcd store and added the windows 7 setup entry to it and every thing is perfect. The windows installation files is inside a folder named sources in the stick same as in the original iso.

The problem is :

When I boot the stick and select setup windows 10 I go through the installation process until I get stuck at:

> windows installation driver is missing browse to get it from a usb or cd ....)

When I select windows 7 setup I successfully installed windows 7 on vmware without any problem.

**BUT....**

If I change the name of the folder that contain the windows 7 installation from sources to any other name the windows 10 installation working perfectly.

If I edit the bcd to take the installation for windows 7 setup from the new folder name it give me the same error as windows 10 setup (windows 7 setup missing drivers...) but now windows 10 setup worked perfectly .

What should I do to make them both working?

Comment: I think this boils down to that you are doing something that MS hasn't prepared for: Having the installation packages of two operating systems in the same partition of a media (I hope I did understand right how you have put the installation image contents on the USB stick). It probably would work if you had separate partitions on the USB stick for the installers, but I guess there might be other issues with that since USB drives rarely have multiple partitions (booting to 2nd partition might not work)... (and I can't anyway help you with how to set up such partitions)

Comment: yah you are right but i still think that there is a way to do it (i think that i have to edit something inside the boot.wim to find the right path of the install.esd not sure yet ) any way thank you so much for your comment...

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure of Windows 10 installation ISO is:

```
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          boot
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          efi
15/11/17  15:35    <DIR>          sources
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          support
15/03/31  03:28               128 autorun.inf
15/10/30  06:08           400,228 bootmgr
15/10/30  05:33         1,147,736 bootmgr.efi
15/10/30  11:35               152 MediaMeta.xml
15/10/30  05:09            80,576 setup.exe
```

The directory structure of Windows 7 installation ISO is:

```
11/04/12  11:38               122 autorun.inf
11/04/12  11:38    <DIR>          boot
11/04/12  11:38           383,786 bootmgr
11/04/12  11:38           669,568 bootmgr.efi
11/04/12  11:38    <DIR>          efi
11/04/12  11:38           106,768 setup.exe
11/04/12  11:38    <DIR>          sources
11/04/12  11:38    <DIR>          support
11/04/12  11:38    <DIR>          upgrade
```

It is obvious that we have some files and directories which cannot be moved to another location! These files and directories are:

```
\boot, \efi

bootmgr
```

I would try following configuration for USB flash drive:

1) copy all Windows 10 files from ISO in the root of USB.

2) rename \sources on USB to \sources10

3) copy Windows 7 ISO \sources directory to \sources7 on USB for example.

4) copy boot entry for "W10 setup" to "W7 setup" in both BCD's (for UEFI and for BIOS booting) and amend paths for "W10 setup" and for "W7 setup" to \sources10 and \sources7 (corresponding paths for "Application Device" and for "OS Device")

5) put MBR and PBR records on USB for BIOS booting.

No guarantee that this configuration will work as it seems the problem is really addressing "install.wim" from "boot.wim" which is used to start the setup process. Microsoft should have made path to "install.wim" relevant to path of "boot.wim" (e.g. to be portable).

EDIT:

And this is the structure of a Windows 10 ISO with both 32 and 64 bit install when created with Media Creation Tool:

```
15/11/25  05:38    <DIR>          boot
15/11/25  05:37    <DIR>          efi
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          x64
15/10/30  09:32    <DIR>          x86
15/03/31  03:13                43 autorun.inf
15/10/30  06:08           400,228 bootmgr
15/10/30  05:33         1,147,736 bootmgr.efi
15/10/30  05:08            79,552 setup.exe
```

where \x64:

```
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          .
15/11/25  05:39    <DIR>          ..
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          boot
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          efi
15/11/25  05:38    <DIR>          sources
15/10/30  11:43    <DIR>          support
15/03/31  03:28               128 autorun.inf
15/10/30  06:08           400,228 bootmgr
15/10/30  05:33         1,147,736 bootmgr.efi
15/10/30  11:35               152 MediaMeta.xml
15/10/30  05:09            80,576 setup.exe
```

\x64 is a complete copy of single Windows 10-64bit ISO.

BCD boot entry:

[image]

Comment: actually i tried this when i change the folder name sources to any other name the windows installation start asking for drivers .    thank you for trying to help me bro.